# Why is glucose used in oral rehydration therapy?

Tags: microbiology, glucose

What is mechanism of action of glucose in the intestine to reduce the watery and electrolyte secretion?

Answer (score 1):

Oral Rehydration Therapy uses electrolyte solution containing some glucose. It is because, the absorption of electrolytes is more efficient when glucose is added. Sodium uptake from intestine is carried out by sodium glucose co-transporters.